# Nginx redirect crash after testing a few times

Tags: nginx

Currently i have 2 server-blocks, server block 1 and server block 2, my goal is to make it such that server block 1 only listen and serve over port 2206 and server block 2 only listen and serve over port 8206 , i have closed port 80 and open port 2206 and 8206.

I inputted this code into my nginx block so that it will redirect anything that is not server-block-1 to port: 8206 and vice versa​

```
if($host != server-block-1.test.com) {
return 301 http://$host:8206$request_uri; }
```

Below is the full serverBlock code for both blocks

serverBlock1

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {

        root /var/serverblock1/test.ml;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name server-block-1.test.ml;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen [::]:2206 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 2206 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server-block-1.test.ml/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server-block-1.test.ml/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    error_page 497 =301 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri; # redirect http to https
    if ($host != server-block-1.test.ml) {
        return 301 http://$host:8206$request_uri;
    }

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}

server {
    if ($host = server-block-1.test.ml) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name server-block-1.test.ml;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

serverBlock2

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {

        listen 8206 http2;
        listen [::]:8206 http2;

        root /var/serverblock2/test.ml;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name server-block-2.test.ml;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
        if ($host != server-block-2.test.ml) {
                return 301 https://$host:2206$request_uri;
        }

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

It works to a certain extent where it directs but after testing a few times, the web page crashes and it will recover after a while.

Nginx error log

```
2021/03/19 04:00:20 [info] 23230#23230: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:00:25 [notice] 23674#23674: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:05:53 [info] 30543#30543: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:05:57 [notice] 30785#30785: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:13:18 [info] 12175#12175: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:13:31 [notice] 13520#13520: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:30:01 [info] 20276#20276: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:30:06 [notice] 20773#20773: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:36:57 [info] 31584#31584: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:37:05 [notice] 32370#32370: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:45:03 [info] 17694#17694: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:45:06 [notice] 18009#18009: signal process started
2021/03/19 04:48:34 [info] 7388#7388: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2021/03/19 04:48:39 [notice] 7884#7884: signal process started
```

Would like to ask why would it crash and is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: It sounds more like cache problem to me. Have you checked if you have enough resources self when site starts crashing

Comment: That depends on what kind of back-end you are using

Comment: I am using Microsoft Azure Virtual machine and using Nignx to host my websites

Comment: Have you tried digging inside nginx error logs or virtual machine error logs?

Comment: hi, i tried looking into the error logs but there is nothing out of the ordinary. I have also updated my post by providing my codes for both serverBlocks. Would like to ask if there is any error  in the redirecting in these codes